# Producing the intersection of several sequences

Tags: c#, performance, linq, set

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect#answer-1674779) I have created a method that produce the set intersection of several sequences:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{   
    using (IEnumerator<IEnumerable<TSource>> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        //if there is no first element return an empty list
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        IEnumerable<TSource> firstSequence = sourceIterator.Current;
        if (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            //create a hashset of the first sequence
            HashSet<TSource> hashSet = new HashSet<TSource>(firstSequence);

            //intersect the other sequences
            do
            {                       
                hashSet.IntersectWith(sourceIterator.Current);
            }
            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext());
            foreach (TSource element in hashSet)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
        else
        {                   
            //if there is only one sequence, return it without any intersection
            foreach (TSource element in firstSequence)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm particularly annoyed that the method is lot of times slower than the following implementation, when there is only one sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource>
          Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    return source.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y));
}
```

I already put a special test and code path when there is only one element, but it does not seems to be enough. Beside this problem, is there any obvious way to optimize the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let me point out that you shouldn't name this extension method as you have named: `Intersect()`. The name `Intersect()` already exists and will return the intersection of two collections.  Your method is intersecting a collection of collections with each other.  It <s>should</s> *must* be named differently.  I would suggest `IntersectAll()` or possibly `IntersectMany()`.

I feel your implementation for the case of a single collection is wrong.  You are performing a set operation here.  You need to ensure that for all cases, you maintain set semantics.  You assume that for a single collection that you may return that collection.  But what if that collection contains duplicates?  You would need to filter out those duplicates.  The aggregated version should as well.

---

With that in mind, I would change your implementation like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectAll<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var set = new HashSet<TSource>(enumerator.Current);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            set.IntersectWith(enumerator.Current);
        foreach (var item in set)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you did your testing but even with your implementation, I still get much faster results, even in the single collection case.  Tested in LINQPad with optimizations enabled:

Your implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectAll1<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{   
    using (IEnumerator<IEnumerable<TSource>> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        //if there is no first element return an empty list
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        IEnumerable<TSource> firstSequence = sourceIterator.Current;
        if (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            //create a hashset of the first sequence
            HashSet<TSource> hashSet = new HashSet<TSource>(firstSequence);

            //intersect the other sequences
            do
            {                       
                hashSet.IntersectWith(sourceIterator.Current);
            }
            while (sourceIterator.MoveNext());
            foreach (TSource element in hashSet)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
        else
        {                   
            //if there is only one sequence, return it without any intersection
            foreach (TSource element in firstSequence)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectAll2<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var set = new HashSet<TSource>(enumerator.Current);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            set.IntersectWith(enumerator.Current);
        foreach (var item in set)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectAllControl<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    return source.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y));
}
```

```
void Main()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var collections = Enumerable.Range(0, 500)
        .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(rng.Next(0, 50), 100).ToArray())
        .Cast<IEnumerable<int>>()
        //.Take(1)
        .ToArray();

    const int Iterations = 1000; // 1000000 for single collection

    object result1 = null;
    var timer1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        result1 = collections.IntersectAll1().ToList();
    timer1.Stop();
    result1.Dump(String.Format("result1: {0}", timer1.Elapsed));

    object result2 = null;
    var timer2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        result2 = collections.IntersectAll2().ToList();
    timer2.Stop();
    result2.Dump(String.Format("result2: {0}", timer2.Elapsed));

    object controlResult = null;
    var controlTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        controlResult = collections.IntersectAllControl().ToList();
    controlTimer.Stop();
    controlResult.Dump(String.Format("controlResult: {0}", controlTimer.Elapsed));
}
```

Note: The `ToList()` calls were needed on all invocations to ensure that the intersections are actually generated.

Run on my machine with multiple collections:

```
result1:       00:00:01.0210291
result2:       00:00:01.0285069
controlResult: 00:00:03.1512838
```

And with a single collection:

```
result1:       00:00:02.9254441
result2:       00:00:04.8505489
controlResult: 00:00:00.2102433
```

---

I have to apologize, I have changed my review as I wrote this due to some details I overlooked as I was writing. Thank you mjolka for pointing out my mistake.

For multiple collections, the new implementations will always be a win over the aggregation.  In the aggregated approach, each sub-instersection needs to be determined for every collection.  In our new implementations, only a single set intersection needs to be maintained.

The new implementations will not beat out the aggregate method in the single collection case however, because the aggregate will simply pass the collection through as the result untouched.  The new implementations will always do some bit of processing.  However again, I feel that if set semantics were preserved, this difference will probably be cancelled out anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestions. About test results, try the following : one list containing a lot of items (3 millions). In that case, the implementation that use `Aggregate` is at least 10x faster.

Comment: Well yes, in that case, the aggregate will definitely be much faster. There is only one item in the collection and it is not processed any further, it is just passed through with no modifications. In your implementation, it has an extra layer of indirection due to the generator that we created. However that all will probably be negated when you introduce the set semantics.

Comment: Actually, I tried bumping up the collection to contain 3 million for the single item case and the aggregate was still slower for me (2-4x).

Comment: Your benchmarking is flawed as `collections.IntersectAll1()` and `collections.IntersectAll2()` are not enumerated. Try adding `.Count()` to see what I mean.

Comment: @mjolka: Ah you're right. I totally overlooked that.